# JavaCC regex that ignores everything until a specific string

Tags: regex, token, javacc

So I have a function on javacc:

```
void parseDSL() throws SemanticException #void :
{}
{
    <ALL> "/*@mat" dslStatements() "*/" <ALL> <EOF>
}
```

My objective is to ignore everything until the "/*@mat" matches and after the parsing ignores everythings until EOF.
I'm really struggling to find a regular expressions that works here.
One example of a file that should pass is:

```
public class blabla {
    int i=1;/*@mat
    in float B[100];
    in float C[100];
    in int A[9];
    in int Z[9];
    out float D[];
    D=A*(B+C-Z)+A*Z;
    */boolean a;
}
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what lexical states are for.  See the documentation and FAQ for more information.  Roughly what you want is

```
<DEFAULT> SKIP: { < ~[] > }  // Skip everything up to "/*@mat"
<DEFAULT> TOKEN: { < STARTMAT: "/*@mat" > : GO } 
<GO> TOKEN: { <IN : "in" >
            | <OUT : "out" >
            | .... other rules go here ....
            | <ENDMAT : "*/" > : DEFAULT // On a "*/" go back to skipping. 
}
```